# How to implement message queue with Spring Integration and MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-integration, message-queue, spring-data-mongodb

How to configure Spring Integration so processed messages are deleted from colection. In MongoDB console I can simply call:

```
db.messages.findAndModify({ remove:true })
```

but in MongoDbMessageSource is only reading messages

```
mongoTemplate.find(..)
```

I guess it can by done with some delete in transaction. But I was not able to figure out easy nice solution.

Inbound part of my configuration:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public IntegrationFlow pollMessages(MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory, SomeService someService) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            mongoMessageSource(mongoDbFactory),
            c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
            .handle(someService, "process")
            .get();
}

@Bean
@Autowired
public MongoDbMessageSource mongoMessageSource(MongoDbFactory mongo) {
    MongoDbMessageSource messageSource = new MongoDbMessageSource(mongo, new LiteralExpression("{}"));
    messageSource.setEntityClass(MessageEntity.class);
    messageSource.setCollectionNameExpression(new LiteralExpression("messages"));

    return messageSource;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. To achieve such a requirement you need to take a look into the:

```
/**
 * Specify the {@link TransactionSynchronizationFactory} to attach a
 * {@link org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronization}
 * to the transaction around {@code poll} operation.
 * @param transactionSynchronizationFactory the TransactionSynchronizationFactory to use.
 * @return the spec.
 */
public PollerSpec transactionSynchronizationFactory(
        TransactionSynchronizationFactory transactionSynchronizationFactory) {
```

And really perform a delete from the collection on the `TransactionSynchronizationProcessor.processAfterCommit()`.

See [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/transactions.html#transaction-synchronization) for more information.

For XML configuration we have this test-case:

```
<int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundAdapterWithOnSuccessDisposition"
                                     channel="replyChannel"
                                     query="{'name' : 'Bob'}"
                                     auto-startup="false">

    <int:poller fixed-delay="200" max-messages-per-poll="1">
        <int:advice-chain  synchronization-factory="syncFactory">
            <bean
                    class="org.springframework.integration.mongodb.config.MongoDbInboundChannelAdapterIntegrationTests.TestMessageSourceAdvice" />
            <tx:advice>
                <tx:attributes>
                    <tx:method name="*" />
                </tx:attributes>
            </tx:advice>
        </int:advice-chain>
    </int:poller>
</int-mongodb:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="syncFactory">
    <int:before-commit expression="@documentCleaner.remove(#mongoTemplate, payload, headers.mongo_collectionName)"/>
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.integration.transaction.PseudoTransactionManager" />
```

Something similar can be done with Java DSL as well.

You need a `DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory` and `ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor` to configure on the matter. Right, the same `PseudoTransactionManager` can be used.

Although you also can consider to call `remove/update` manually in the end of flow.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I tried to reimplement it with Java configuration but with no success. I will call manual remove in the end of flow.

Comment: If it comes at the end of the flow, does that make the operation not parallelizable across multiple workers (as two or processes could process the same data)?

Comment: Doesn't sounds like related question. Please, raise a new SO thread with more details and we will try to help you. Thanks for understanding

Comment: No problem! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51676101/implementing-a-mongodb-inbound-flow-with-spring-integration