# Implementing a MongoDB Inbound Flow with Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

We will have a Mongo collection contain multiple units of work. My idea is that the document will have a status field with four options: UNPROCESSED, PROCESSING, DONE, FAILED. Spring Integration will be configured to read from this db and process the messages stored there.

An inbound Mongo DSL flow will read from the collection based on a value of UNPROCESSED:

```
MongoDbMessageSource messageSource = new MongoDbMessageSource(mongo, new LiteralExpression("{'status' : 'UNPROCESSED'}"));
return IntegrationFlows.from(messageSource)...
```

Here's the problem: if I have a few worker machines reading from the same database I want to prevent them from operating on the same rows of UNPROCESSED data given my poller utilizes a conservative value for `maxMessagesPerPoll` or message processing takes a while.

It seems the right venue is to use `TransactionSynchronizationFactory` to define a **ProcessBeforeCommit** phase to update the status to PROCESSING, and a **ProcessAfterCommit** phase to update the status to DONE or FAILED. However, the mechanism to add this is not clear to me looking at the API for Pollers and TransactionManagers. There are examples in XML, but none that I can see utilizing DSL.

I would also want to ensure that **ProcessBeforeCommit** happens at the time of data base read and not after processing... does it? Also, if this is not the optimal way to engineer a solution that reads from a Mongo collection please feel free to suggest a better architecture.

Answer (score 1):

No, `ProcessBeforeCommit` and `ProcessAfterCommit` are very close callbacks. They definitely happen in the end of your process. Let's consider you have a method like:

```
@Transactional
void foo() {}
```

When you call such a method, the transaction starts *before* entering a method body. 
When we exit a method body after its execution, the *beforeCommit* callback is performed. It may fail because during our process an external connection (DB ?) may be lost. And only if it is OK, we proceed to the `afterCommit`.

What you are asking can be done via `AbstractMessageSourceAdvice` implementation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#conditional-pollers. So, in the `afterReceive()` implementation you can update your document to the `PROCESSING` and even decided to return `null` instead of the message: just because its status in the DB is already `PROCESSING`. Such an `Advice` can be injected into the `PollerSpec`:

```
/**
 * Specify AOP {@link Advice}s for the {@code pollingTask}.
 * @param advice the {@link Advice}s to use.
 * @return the spec.
 */
public PollerSpec advice(Advice... advice) {
```

The `DONE` and `FAILED` really can be achieved via `TransactionSynchronizationFactoryBean` applied to the `PollerSpec`:

```
/**
 * Specify the {@link TransactionSynchronizationFactory} to attach a
 * {@link org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronization}
 * to the transaction around {@code poll} operation.
 * @param transactionSynchronizationFactory the TransactionSynchronizationFactory to use.
 * @return the spec.
 */
public PollerSpec transactionSynchronizationFactory(
```

Comment: I feel like an even better solution is to configure the MongoDBMessageSource class to allow it to do an updateQuery instead of just query. If you think it's a good idea I can work on a PR for that.

Comment: Sounds really good. And yes: that is fully natural and is aligned with what we have in the `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter`. And also this is not a first request though: https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/mongodb/issues/3. Thank you for considering contribution: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.adoc

Comment: @ArtemBilan did MongoDBMessageSource ever get updated to support the use of updateQuery over query?  I'm assuming no since I can't seem to find anything about it in the docs.

Comment: That feature is available since version `5.5`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/mongodb.html. 
> Starting with version 5.5, the `MongoDbMessageSource` can be configured with an `updateExpression`,